# What is the use of >>= or <<= compound assignment in c++?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and haven't seen such a declaration in programs anywhere. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are called compound assignment operators. There are almost 10 of them in C/C++ language. ex `+=  -=  *=  <<= >>=`. When one of the operand is same as the variable to which final result to be assigned is same, in a binary operation this can be used as a short hand syntax. Ex `a=a+b` can be written as `a+=b`. in the same `a=a<<2` can be written as `a<<=2`. This type of syntactic sugar is also supported by other languages too.

Answer (score 2):

For integral type

i >>= 3;

is equal to:

i = i >> 3;

ie bitwise shift variable `i` right (in his case) in place.

For user defined classes it can be overloaded to whatever functionality author wants this operator to implement

Answer (score 1):

Use of compound assignment operators is encouraged since it evaluates the LHS only once.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators**
>
> ...
>
> 7 The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op = E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1 op E2` except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

If you have a function that returns a reference to an object, it is more efficient and less error prone when you use a compound assignment operator.

E.g.

```
std::vector<int> v(10, 1);
v[4] <<= 2;
```

is better than

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
v[4] = v[4] << 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Left shift assignment   `<<=`

`x <<= y` Shift x left by y bits

Right shift assignment  `>>=`

`x >>= y`  Shift x right by y bits

[Read This](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/38-bitwise-operators/) to know more about bitwise operators in c++.

Answer (score 0):

In c in general, an operator with an equals following it is shorthand for "do the operation, and put the result back in the same variable."

```
x = x >> 4; // shift x right by 4 bits
x >>= 4;    // exactly the same as above
x <<= 3;  // shift x left by 3 bits
```

This assumes that x is a numeric type like long, unsigned short, etc.

If x is not numeric, then the original programmer probably defined the operation as an overloaded operator in c++, for example, lopping off n characters from a string.